# Doctrine manager class injection to controller doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, bundle

In my bundle I need to initialize my doctrine manager class (as a service and using ManagerRegistry) in constructor of controller, but symfony still throws this exception:

> Type error: Too few arguments to function AdminBundle\Controller\RegistraceController::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\apache\htdocs\mujProjekt\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver.php on line 198 and exactly 1 expected

Controller:

```
namespace AdminBundle\Controller;

use AdminBundle\Manager\AdminManager;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

/**
* Class DefaultController
* @package AdminBundle\Controller
* @Route("/registrace")
*/
class RegistraceController extends Controller
{
   /**
    * @var AdminManager
    */
   private $manager;

   public function __construct(AdminManager $manager)
   {
       $this->manager = $manager;
   }

   ...
```

AdminManager:

```
namespace AdminBundle\Manager;

use AdminBundle\Entity\Uzivatel;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class AdminManager
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $Doctrine)
    {
        $this->em = $Doctrine->getManager('default');
    }

 ...
```

AdminBundle\Resources\config\services.yml :

```
services:
#    admin.example:
#        class: AdminBundle\Example
#        arguments: ["@service_id", "plain_value", "%parameter%"]
    admin.admin_manager:
        class: AdminBundle\Manager\AdminManager
        arguments:
            ["@doctrine"]
```

I tried to clear cache, but no success. The services.yml from AdminBundle is correctly included in config.yml.

orm config in config.yml:

```
    orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                AdminBundle:  ~
```

I'm using Symfony 3.3 and PHP 7.1.

Comment: Since you are using S3.3+ you might take a look at injecting your admin service directly into the action: http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#controller-accessing-services This is all new stuff so if you are following older tutorials then it will be easy to get confused.

Comment: Thank you Cerad for your tip! It's useful feature a it works well in my controller now.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to inject your AdminManager in your RegistraceController, you have to define the RegistraceController as a service. Look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html. There are some drawbacks of this approach, because you do not inherit from Symfony‘s base Controller. So, you have to inject the Router and the Template Engine too, if you need them. But I like defining my Controller as services. It‘s much cleaner when you see dependencies.

Instead of this, you can use the Symfony Container inside your controller as an Inversion Of Controll Container and get your service with $this->get('admin.admin_manager'); from inside your action.

Comment: You might want to direct their attention to the service argument in the annotated route definition: @Route(service="admin.admin_manager") which is needed to tell the routing system to pull the controller from the container.

Comment: You mistyped your @Route definition. It should be @Route(service="name_of_controller_service") and not the service name of the service he would actually inject in the controller. Apart from that, you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

So i think your service yml need to look like that:

```
services:
    admin.admin_manager:
        class: AdminBundle\Manager\AdminManager
        arguments: ["@doctrine"]
    admin.admin_controller:
        class: AdminBundle\Controller\RegistraceController
        arguments: ["@admin.admin_manager"]
```

Look up here [Symfony Service Container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html)

Hope it will help!

Greetings :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your replies. Fortunately I solved my problem by adding this to services in app/config/services.yml.

```
    AdminBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/AdminBundle/Controller'
    public: true
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```